# Apache usergrid tomcat error

Tags: apache, tomcat7, usergrid

I am trying to deploy apache usergrid stack on my localhost. I placed ROOT.war in to /vat/lib/tomcat7/webapps. After restart tomcat when I access http://localhost:8080 then I get nothing in response. When I checked the logs of tomcat, I get following error in localhost log.

```
    Mar 19, 2016 5:51:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 19, 2016 5:51:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.usergrid.rest.ShutdownListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/usergrid/rest/ShutdownListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.apache.usergrid.rest.ShutdownListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Mar 19, 2016 5:51:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

If anyone has the solution please help.

Answer (score 0):

The UnsupportedClassVersionError exception usually means that you are trying to run some Java code that is compiled for a newer version of Java, on an older version of Java.

Usergrid 2 requires Java 8 so make sure that you are using a Java 8 JDK.

See the Usergrid Deployment Guide for requirements and instructions:
https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/deployment-guide.html